# Laravel - Sortby date after GroupBy callback

Tags: laravel, sorting, collections, laravel-5

I'm creating a collection and using a groupBy to group items together depending on the month, however after this I then want to it to go back to ascending date order (Jan/Feb/Mar). Here is my function that I'm using below;

```
    private function monthByMonthAgentReferrals() {
         $case = Case::where('start_date', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(360))
                     ->where('source', 'AGENT')->get()
                     ->groupBy(function($key) {
               return Carbon::parse($key->start_date)->format('m');
         }); 
         return $case;
    }
```

At the moment when I display the results I get a return of the months in a random order;

```
Collection {#1982 ▼
  #items: array:12 [▼
    12 => Collection {#1321 ▶}
   "07" => Collection {#1322 ▶}
    10 => Collection {#1320 ▶}
   "05" => Collection {#1991 ▶}
   "06" => Collection {#1990 ▶}
   "08" => Collection {#1989 ▶}
   "01" => Collection {#1988 ▶}
    11 => Collection {#1987 ▶}
   "09" => Collection {#1986 ▶}
   "02" => Collection {#1985 ▶}
   "03" => Collection {#1984 ▶}
   "04" => Collection {#1983 ▶}
  ]
}
```

How would I go about sorting by 'start_date' again? or would it be better to sort by the array key? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private function monthByMonthAgentReferrals() {
     $case = Case::where('start_date', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(360))
                 ->where('source', 'AGENT')->get()
                 ->groupBy(function($key) {
           return Carbon::parse($key->start_date)->format('m');
     })->toArray();

     ksort($case);

     return collect($case); 
}
```

Converts the collection to an array, use the function ksort on the array and then recollect the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```
$case = Case::where('start_date', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(360))
                 ->selectRaw('table_name.*')
                 ->where('source', 'AGENT')
                 ->groupBy(function($key) {
           return Carbon::parse($key->start_date)->format('m');
})->orderBy('start_date')->get();
```

Comment: I've tried that, but I get the error 'strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given'

Comment: problem is in function inside `groupBy`.